# Solve $Ax=b$ repeatedly where $A$ is a sparse weighted Laplacian matrix with changing weights

Tags: sparse-matrix, iterative-method, linear-system

In the problem I am dealing with, I require to repeatedly solve $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a weighted Laplacian matrix of a sparse graph. The right-hand side remains constant. However each time I solve the system, only **one** weight of the graph changes, effectively changing 4 coefficients in the Laplacian matrix (2 diagonal and 2 off-diagonal entries).

I am currently using the GMRES solver in Petsc, and using the previous solution as the initial guess. However the coefficient changes by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude, and it is not as fast as if the coefficient were changing slightly.

I was wondering if there is anyway to solve this problem any faster than what I have been currently doing. Perhaps something which takes advantage of the linear nature of the problem and involves a direct method.

Comment: Doesn't changing one single weight lead to a rank-1 update of $A$? If so, why not use [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula)?

Comment: How big and dense is your matrix?  Is using a sparse direct factorization possible?  If so, then as Rodrigo commented, using Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury would be a good approach.

Comment: $A$ is large (> 1e6 entries) and sparse. Storing the inverse is impractical.  I implemented Sherman-Morrison for one rank-1 update of $A_0$ , avoiding computing the inverse by using LU decomposition of $A_0$ to compute the solution of the new system $A_1 x=b$.  However, for a further rank-1 update of $A_1$, the solution of $A_2 x=b$ requires a recursive application of  Sherman-Morrison which would quickly become costly after a few rank-1 updates of the initial matrix $A_0$ . Is there a way to avoid explicitly computing the inverse while avoiding the recursion which arises when using LU?

Comment: Have you considered Krylov subspace recycling? This idea is suitable for sequences of large linear systems where the matrix and/or the right hand side change "slowly". I'll refer you to [this paper by Parks](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/48161/040607277.pdf?sequence=1) and [related work](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/sturler/#Publications) by Eric de Sturler and collaborators.

Comment: You don't want or need to store the inverse.   You might be able to store an LU factorization.

Comment: Brian - It is not clear to me how to update the LU factorization using Sherman-Morrison. However I think the Woodbury matrix identity is what I can potentially use. I will check if I can get a performance boost over using Krylov methods.

Comment: GoHokies - Thanks for the references. These are interesting. As far as I know Petsc does not have this recycling option. I will look into implementing this to see if it gives me a boost over simply using the GMRES solver.

Comment: 1e6 entries in a sparse matrix is quite small, with storage requirements measured in megabytes rather than gigabytes.  If you're saying that the size of the matrix is 1e6 by 1e6, then depending on the sparsity it may or may not be reasonable to compute a sparse factorization of the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me that you are dealing with a sequence of linear systems $A_j x_j = b$, where $A_{j+1}$ is a low rank modification of $A_{j}$.

In your case, I would investigate if the Krylov subspace $K = \text{range $V$}$ which you have built to solve one linear system, say, $A x  = b$ is relevant for the solution of the next problem, i.e., $$(A + \Delta A) (x + \Delta x) =b.$$ Specifically, I would first solve the small dense problem $$V^T(A + \Delta A) V z = V^T b$$ and use $x_0 = Vz$ as my initial guess for $x + \Delta x$ when applying GMRES to the next problem.

I am gambling that this initial guess will serve you better than the solution of the original problem.

In your case, the small dense problem is a low rank modification of the Hessenberg system $$ H w = V^T b = e_1, \quad H = V^T A V$$ which is solved internally by GMRES. Here you may be well served with an application of the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Saunders wrote a sparse LU package that can do rank-1 updates, [LUSOL](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lusol/). You could try to use that, since you write that direct solvers are viable for your problem.